# How to change base root for all TinyMCE static files?

Tags: javascript, frontend, tinymce, editor

I tried config my tiny mce editor, and all my static files are at specific path /tinymce/...

this is my init for tiny mce

```
        init={{
          content_style: `
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400&display=swap');
            body { background-color: #ffffff;
                font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
                font-weigth: normal;
                font-size: 14px; color: #111; line-height: 24px; margin: 0;
              }
            .error {
              color: #ff0001;
            }
          `,
          mode: 'exact',
          theme: 'modern',
          skin: 'material',
          menubar: false,
          plugins: 'advlist lists',
          advlist_bullet_styles: 'square',
          toolbar: defaultToolbarOptions,
          height,
        }}
```

by default he try found theme at /themes/modern/theme.js, but it locate at /tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js

how to change default route for themes, plugins, skins etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TinyMCE 5.x, you can use the `base_url` configuration option to accomplish this:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#base_url